# SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME

Tags: windows-7, oracle, oracle-11g

I am getting following error message when i write `sqlplus` on command prompt

```
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
```

Here are the path details

[image]

[image]

[image]

Net Configuration Assistance is not working too. It is not getting launched from Program Files and while accessing directly it gives following error

```
C:\Oracle\product\11.1.0\db_1\BIN>netca.bat
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:/Oracle/product/11.1.0/db_
1;/oui/lib/win32/oraInstaller.dll
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1650)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:769)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:968)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.win32.OiipwWin32NativeCalls.loadNativeLib(
OiipwWin32NativeCalls.java:1491)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.win32.OiipwWin32NativeCalls.<clinit>(Oiipw
Win32NativeCalls.java:47)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgEnvironment.getEnv(OiipgEnvironment
.java:210)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgPropertyLoader.initUnixPtrFileLoc(O
iipgPropertyLoader.java:213)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgPropertyLoader.<clinit>(OiipgProper
tyLoader.java:126)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicStandardInventorySession.updateProperties(
OiicStandardInventorySession.java:461)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicStandardInventorySession.initSession(OiicS
tandardInventorySession.java:257)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicStandardInventorySession.initSession(OiicS
tandardInventorySession.java:231)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicStandardInventorySession.initSession(OiicS
tandardInventorySession.java:180)
        at oracle.net.ca.NetCA.getHomeInfo(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ca.NetCA.main(Unknown Source)


java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no oraInstaller in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1682)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:822)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:993)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.win32.OiipwWin32NativeCalls.loadNativeLib(
OiipwWin32NativeCalls.java:1514)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.osd.win32.OiipwWin32NativeCalls.<clinit>(Oiipw
Win32NativeCalls.java:47)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgEnvironment.getEnv(OiipgEnvironment
.java:210)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgPropertyLoader.initUnixPtrFileLoc(O
iipgPropertyLoader.java:213)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiip.oiipg.OiipgPropertyLoader.<clinit>(OiipgProper
tyLoader.java:126)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicStandardInventorySession.updateProperties(
OiicStandardInventorySession.java:461)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicStandardInventorySession.initSession(OiicS
tandardInventorySession.java:257)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicStandardInventorySession.initSession(OiicS
tandardInventorySession.java:231)
        at oracle.sysman.oii.oiic.OiicStandardInventorySession.initSession(OiicS
tandardInventorySession.java:180)
        at oracle.net.ca.NetCA.getHomeInfo(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ca.NetCA.main(Unknown Source)
Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is -1
```

Comment: Answer is [here][1] on StackOverflow


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095960/sp2-0750-you-may-need-to-set-oracle-home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved, since i attempted various solutions so i don't exactly remember, but i think it got solved by following two things

1-`ORACLE_HOME` should not contain anything after the path i.e. no `\`, `;`,`,`

2-I added an environment variable named `LANG` with value `American_America.we8iso8859p15`